# Is there a way to infer equivalence of two instances based on multiple asserted DataProperties

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege

Say you have an ontology like the described below:

```
ex:Stick a owl:Class;

ex:hasWidth a owl:DataTypeProperty;
ex:hasHeight a owl:DataTypeProperty;

ex:Instance1 a ex:Stick;
    ex:hasWidth "1";
    ex:hasHeight "20".

ex:Instance2 a ex:Stick;
    ex:hasWidth "1";
    ex:hasHeight "20".

ex:Instance3 a ex:Stick;
    ex:hasWidth "2";
    ex:hasHeight "20".

ex:Instance4 a ex:Stick;
    ex:hasWidth "1";
    ex:hasHeight "30".
```

Now I am looking for a way to infer that `ex:Instance1 owl:SameAs ex:Instance2` and none of the others are equivalent but it seems like I cannot access the values of an individual to compare it to others.

I have tried using the owl:HasKey function but this can only take one dataTypeProperty at a time and not the combination of multiple DataProperties. When you add a owl:HasKey statement for both hasWidth and hasHeight your ontology will become inconsistent in the cases of ex:Instance3 and ex:Instance4 in combination with ex:Instance1 and ex:Instance2.

Comment: Not possible in OWL, you need rules like SWRL

Comment: and `owl:DataTypeProperty` is wrong, it has to be `owl:DatatypeProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried using the owl:hasKey function but this can only take one DatatypeProperty at a time and not the combination of multiple data properties.

In Protégé, use comma:

[image: three Protege views]

Manchester syntax:

```
Class: Stick
    HasKey: hasHeight, hasWidth
```

Turtle syntax:

```
:Stick a owl:Class ;
       owl:hasKey ( :hasHeight :hasWidth ) .
```

More info: [9.5 Keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Keys).

---

Using SWRL:

```
hasHeight(?x, ?h) ^ hasHeight(?y, ?h) ^ hasWidth(?x, ?w) ^ hasWidth(?y, ?w) -> sameAs(?x, ?y)
```